# php fails parsing on one machine but not the other

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, web-services

I would ask in Chat, but I don't have enough points yet.

I am trying to migrate a server from a deployed setting to a virtual machine running in virtualbox. All networking works fine in the virtual machine. I have no problem posting the code, but I think it is too large and too many files.

I am completely lost. I have

1. Installed Ubuntu Server (updated etc)
2. Installed php, apache, mysql, phpmyadmin, etc
3. `ssh`'d into the current server
   copied the files using `tar -zcvf ./html_files_copy.tar.gz ./html/*`
4. copied mysql stuff using `mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases > db_copy.sql`
5. deployed both the html / php files and the mysql database

No matter what I do though, the server generates a blank page. I have looked into this as much as I can figure out and it seems that php is failing on parsing the php code.

How can I fix this and have the php not fail, and why would it work on one machine and not the other? I can copy the stuff back to the old server and it WORKS!? Mysql tables look EXACTLY the same too.

Does it make sense that the completely blank page (debug info is turned on, not sure why it doesn't say anything) is a parsing error caused by the newer PHP not knowing one version older functions anymore?

Is there a list somewhere I can use to search the code for suspect functions?

---

To get the following info I used `phpinfo()` in a php file, `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a` from terminal using ssh

### - New Server

- PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 with Apache/2.4.7
- Ubuntu 14.04.01
- mysql Client API version 5.5.40
- Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

### - Old Server

- PHP Version
  5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4, with   Apache/2.4.7
- on Ubuntu 14.04
- mysql Client API version 5.5.40
- Linux linuxdesk 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 13 15:45:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Are there errors showing up in your log files?

Comment: the new server serves the phpinfo file without any trouble?  Then php is ok and you need to debug your code.  Maybe you've got something hard-coded to an ip address or something like that.

Comment: I'm trying to debug it, but I didn't write it and I'm not that well versed in PHP. Also, I'm sorry this is silly, but where should I look for the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the PHP log-file or enable error display using the [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) flag. Also enable logging of all errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and verify these settings with `phpinfo()`.